# Is it required to typedef a primitive type to an enum?

Tags: objective-c, enums, header, typedef, anonymous-types

I was looking through the `NSString` header file to see how Apple writes their enumerations and came across this piece of code:

```
enum {
    NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy = 1,
    NSStringEncodingConversionExternalRepresentation = 2
};
typedef NSUInteger NSStringEncodingConversionOptions;
```

This leaves me with a couple questions.

1. Why have they used anonymous enumerations? Is this method advantageous?
2. Is the `typedef NSUInteger NSStringEncodingConversionOptions;` line a good idea to include normally, or is it only used here because they have declared an anonymous enumeration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That strange-looking definition is there to clearly define the bit-width and the signed-ness of an enum in a code both in 64-bit and 32-bit environment. It's detailed in this [Apple document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/64BitChangesCocoa/64BitChangesCocoa.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004247-CH4-SW8), but let me write down the summary here.

Apple in the past used the standard typedef enums before, as in

```
typedef enum { .... } NSEnumTypeName;
```

before 64bit-32bit universal binaries were (re)introduced. (I used "re" because the FAT binaries have been there since the NeXTStep days. Anyway.)

However, this makes the bit-width and the signed-ness of the typedef'd type `NSEnumTypeName` to be implementation-defined as specified in the [Official Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), see 6.7.2.2.4.

That makes it even trickier to write a code which can be compiled with various compilers and with various bit-width.

So Apple switched from the standard enum to the anonymous enum with a corresponding typedef to a specific signed/unsigned integer type.