# Is the following syntax is correct for an enum?

Tags: objective-c, enums, typedef

```
enum  {
  ValidationLoginFailed=2000,
  ValidationSessionTokenExpired=2001,
  ValidationSessionTokenInvalid=2002,
  ValidationEmailNotFound=2003
  ValidationSucccesMIN=ValidationLoginFailed,
  ValidationSucccesMAX=ValidationEmailNotFound,
  ValdationValidSuccessCode=9999,
  ValdationInvalidCode=10000

}; 
typedef int ValidationStatusCodes;
```

please help me out.

Comment: Although it wouldn't affect the validity of the syntax, you misspelled `Success` as `Succces` in `ValidationSucccesMIN` and `ValidationSucccesMAX`.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `ValidationStatusCodes` means `int`, not your anonymous `enum` type. So they aren't actually connected in any way.

However, since your `enum` contains `int` values, you could say that there's some sort of relation. You can pass the names of the enumerated values and they will be considered of the `int` or `ValidationStatusCodes` type.

By the way, Apple does something similar to what you do, except they `typedef` their collective names to `NSInteger` or `NSUInteger` instead of `int` or `uint`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748533/is-it-required-to-typedef-a-primitive-type-to-an-enum) for an example.

With all that said, a more common practice is to `typedef` your custom type name directly to the anonymous `enum`, like this:

```
typedef enum {
    ValidationLoginFailed = 2000,
    ValidationSessionTokenExpired = 2001,
    ValidationSessionTokenInvalid = 2002,
    ValidationEmailNotFound = 2003
    ValidationSuccessMIN = ValidationLoginFailed,
    ValidationSuccessMAX = ValidationEmailNotFound,
    ValdationValidSuccessCode = 9999,
    ValdationInvalidCode = 10000
} ValidationStatusCodes;
```

Comment: thanks. in my case. the return type of my method is an enum. so what return type should i give inside the brackets.

Comment: @user: Whether you do `typedef int` or `typedef enum {...}`, your method should return `ValidationStatusCodes`