# Is there anything like a Java enum in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, enums

I have a situation in Objective-C where a Java-style enum would be very helpful. I have a set of layer types, and each layer has its own persistence value associated with it (stored in seconds). I want to keep these layer types in an enum, since they're too similar to make into separate classes, like so:

```
typedef enum {
    ExplosionLayerType,
    FireworkLayerType,
    FireLayerType,
    FireJetLayerType
} FXLayerType;
```

In Java, I could easily associate these two values with something like this:

```java
public enum FXLayerType {
    Explosion(3),
    Firework(6),
    Fire(7),
    FireJet(-1);

    private int persistence;

    FXLayerType(int persistence) {
        this.persistence = persistence;
    }
}
```

Is there a simple way to create a sort of lightweight class like this in Objective-C, or will need to resort to more primitive methods?

EDIT:

Various people have suggested doing something like this:

```
typedef enum {
    ExplosionLayerType = 3,
    FireworkLayerType = 6
} FXLayerType;
```

This will not work for me, since I may have something like this (Java-style enum):

```
Explosion(3),
Firework(6),
Dust(3);
```

In Java, Dust and Explosion will be treated as unique values, but direct assignment with C enums will treat them as being exactly the same.

Comment: Would it be okay to use the int values as the enum values (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785965/is-the-following-syntax-is-correct-for-an-enum) for an example of custom enum values)?

Comment: @perelman: Hmm, I was not aware of that feature. It's definitely possible, though it feels a little hackish.

Comment: @perelman: On second thought, no, I can't, since multiple layer types may share the same persistence value, but must remain unique.

Comment: @JakeKing How exactly does that work? When value `3` is deserialized from a persistent storage, how do you know it should become `DustLayerType` and not `ExplosionLayerType`?

Comment: @hamstergene: The persistence value has nothing to do with persistent storage, sorry if that was confusing. It's simply how long it should stay "alive" in my game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a primitive container for type and value, consider this approach:

```
typedef struct FXLayerValue {
  FXLayerType type;
  int value;
} FXLayerValue;
```

Then again, a class hierarchy may be worth consideration if things become complex or are better handled dynamically. Caveat: if you have a ton of objects to save and/or create, an objc type will be overkill and degrade performance.

Unfortunately, my Java-Fu isn't good enough to know all the lang differences for enums.

Answer (score 2):

To emulate Java enum's we need something which is comparable (can be operands of `==` etc.), which can have fields, and is lightweight. This suggests structs, and optionally pointers to structs. Here is an example of the latter:

FXLayerType.h:

```
typedef const struct { int persistence; } FXLayerType;

extern FXLayerType * const LayerTypeExplosion;
extern FXLayerType * const LayerTypeFirework;
extern FXLayerType * const LayerTypeDust;
```

FXLayerType.m:

```
#import "FXLayerType.h"

const FXLayerType _LayerTypeExplosion = { 3 };
const FXLayerType _LayerTypeFirework = { 6 };
const FXLayerType _LayerTypeDust = { 3 };

FXLayerType * const LayerTypeExplosion = &_LayerTypeExplosion;
FXLayerType * const LayerTypeFirework = &_LayerTypeFirework;
FXLayerType * const LayerTypeDust = &_LayerTypeDust;
```

So `FXLayerType` itself is a constant struct, while as with Obj-C objects we always use pointers to these structs. The implementation creates 3 constant structs and 3 constant pointers to them.

We can now write code such as:

```
FXLayerType *a, *b;
a = LayerTypeDust;
b = LayerTypeExplosion;

NSLog(@"%d, %d\n", a == b, a->persistence == b->persistence);
```

Which will output "0, 1" - `a` and `b` are different enums (0) but have the same persistence (1). Note here `a` and `b` are not constant pointers, only the enum "literals" are defined as constants.

As written this has the disadvantage that you cannot `switch` on an enum value. However if that is needed just add a second field, say `tag`, and init it with a unique value using a real enum, say `FXLayerStyleTag`. You can also remove the indirection if you are happy to always compare tags (e.g. `a.tag ==`b.tag`). This gives you:

FXLayerType.h:

```
typedef enum { ExplosionTag, FireworkTag, DustTag } FXLayerTypeTag;
typedef struct { FXLayerTypeTag tag; int persistence; } FXLayerType;

extern const FXLayerType LayerTypeExplosion;
extern const FXLayerType LayerTypeFirework;
extern const FXLayerType LayerTypeDust;
```

FXLayerType.m:

```
#import "FXLayerType.h"

const FXLayerType LayerTypeExplosion = { ExplosionTag, 3 };
const FXLayerType LayerTypeFirework = { FireworkTag, 6 };
const FXLayerType LayerTypeDust = { DustTag, 3 };
```

Use:

```
FXLayerType a, b;
a = LayerTypeDust;
b = LayerTypeExplosion;

NSLog(@"%d, %d\n", a.tag == b.tag, a.persistence == b.persistence);
```

A difference between the two designs is the first passes around pointers while the second structures, which may be larger. You can combine them, to get `switch`able pointer-based enums - that is left as an exercise!

Both these designs also have the (dis)advantage that the number of enum "literals" can be extended at any time.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you may assign values to the enum keys in C, as they are nothing but ints:

```
typedef enum {
  LayerTypeExplosion = 3,
  LayerTypeFirework = 6,
  LayerTypeFire = 7,
  LayerTypeFireJet = -1
} FXLayerType;
```

You may use them then simply as a *restricted set* of values, to be assigned to a variable of type `FXLayerType`.

```
FXLayerType myLayerType = LayerTypeFirework;
NSLog(@"Value of myLayerType = %i", myLayerType);
// =>  "Value of myLayerType = 6"
```

Comment: To quote another comment of mine: This doesn't work for me, since the types must remain unique. In Java, if I declared two values, `ExplosionLayerType(3)` and `DustLayerType(3)`, they'd share the same persistence value but would remain unique. This will treat them the same way.

Answer (score 0):

This is not 100% equivalent, but this might be an approach you could take in Objective-C. Basically, create several class-level convenience methods to construction the various configuration of FXLayerType.

```
@interface FXLayerType
{
@private
int persistence;
}

+ (FXLayerType*)fireworkLayerType;
+ (FXLayerType*)explosionLayerType;
+ (FXLayerType*)jetLayerType;

@end

@implementation FXLayerType

+ (FXLayerType*)explosionLayerTypeWithPersistence:(int)persistence
{
   FXLayerType* layerType = [[FXLayerType new] autorelease];
   layerType->persistence = persistence;
   return layerType;
}

+ (FXLayerType*)explosionLayerType
{
   return [self explosionLayerTypeWithPersistence:3];
}

+ (FXLayerType*)fireworkLayerType
{
   return [self explosionLayerTypeWithPersistence:6];
}

+ (FXLayerType*)jetLayerType
{
   return [self explosionLayerTypeWithPersistence:-1];
}

@end
```

Usage:

```
FXLayerType* aJetLayerType = [FXLayerType jetLayerType];
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, since the types must remain unique. In Java, if I declared two values, `ExplosionLayerType(3)` and `DustLayerType(3)`, they'd share the same persistence value but would remain unique. This will treat them the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently used the j2objc format for enums. It works rather nicely. Additionally you can auto generate your enums if you are trying to map directly from a java object.

https://code.google.com/p/j2objc/wiki/Enums

However, I did remove the j2objc specific classes from my "Enums". I did not want the additional dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The struct based answers look good on their face but fail when you try to add Objective-C objects into the struct.  Given that limitation, truly emulating the Java-style enum may be more work than it is worth.